# How can i send sms with twilio React JS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frontend, twilio

I've read the Twilio documentation and I can't find a way to send a simple SMS from the frontend using JavaScript/React.

The Twilio documentation just shows how to do that using Node.js(server side).

Actually, I found the documentation a bit awkward because they don't explain the how to do that using the most common programme language on the web.

I'm using postman and it works fine, but on my react code doesn't. The code below was exported from Postman:

```
var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC62761f2bae5c5659cc5eb65d42e5d57e/Messages.json",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Authorization": "Basic hashedAuthToken",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "Postman-Token": "0s41f5ac-2630-40c4-8041-1e5ee513f20d"
    },
    "data": {
            "To": "+353838173123",
            "From": "+18634000432",
            "MessagingServiceSid": "MG3d622e63a343e11a2032b1414560f227",
            "Body": "Test, hi"
    }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: There isn't a safe way to do it in the front-end as you are embedding your authentication credentials.

Comment: the same js that works backend works frontend, its just highly unusual that one would want to send it from the frontend as you will be exposing your credentials to everyone